# Opening different activities from multiple items in a CardView in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating a scrollable menu of different services that I offer and the services are part of an `ArrayList` that populates a `CardView` using `recyclerview`. How can I set up an `onclicklistener` to open multiple activities from the different items clicked on the recycler?

```
productList = new ArrayList<>();
//adding some items to our list
productList.add(
    new TvItems(
        1,
        R.drawable.live,
        "store",
        "store45"
    ));
productList.add(
    new TvItems(
        1,
        R.drawable.jc,
        "account",
        "accounts"
    ));
productList.add(
    new TvItems(
        1,
        R.drawable.prayer,
        "budget",
        "budgeting"
    ));
```

Comment: https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/.  check this post to know clicklistener on recyclerview

Comment: Show your adapter please

Answer (score 2):

hi dear i suggest you to edit your model class.
you have to add Activity type parameter in model as activity or whatever you want then onClicklistener get the name of value and perform your desired class.

```
productList.add(
    new TvItems(
            1,
            R.drawable.jc,
            "account",
            "accounts",
            MainActivity.class
    ));
```

and the in adapter

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getActivity(), list[position].activity);
startActivity(intent);
```

i hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

In the onBindViewHolder() you can actually set the items to the listeners to open multiple activities.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int pos) {
       holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Adapter.this.context.startActivity(new Intent(Adapter.this.context, SecondActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });


    }
```